# Calc() not working with stroke-dashoffset in Safari and Firefox

Tags: css, svg, firefox, safari, css-calc

Trying to use [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc()) with the `stroke-dashoffset` property in Safari (v12+) and Firefox (v84+) results in the browser rendering the value as `0px` instead of the expected value. Chrome behaves as expected.

In the example below, both SVGs should look identical, with the line's stroke extending halfway across the square.

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.withCalc line,
.withoutCalc line {
  stroke-dasharray: 190;
}
.withCalc line {
  stroke-dashoffset: calc(190 / 2);
}
.withoutCalc line {
  stroke-dashoffset: 95;
}
```

```html
<svg class="withCalc" viewBox="0 0 200 200" width="200" height="200">
  <line x1="5" y1="100" x2="195" y2="100" stroke="black"/>
</svg>
<svg class="withoutCalc" viewBox="0 0 200 200" width="200" height="200">
  <line x1="5" y1="100" x2="195" y2="100" stroke="black"/>
</svg>
```

Is this a bug with Safari and Firefox? [Caniuse shows that both should fully support `calc()`](https://caniuse.com/calc). Is there another way to effectively use `calc()` in this situation?

Comment: It does look like a bug - in that FF at least seems to require that units are specified. For example calc(50% / 2) and calc(190px  / 2) are both accepted OK but calc(190 / 2) gives invalid property value. A CSS variable is also accepted as long as its calc has a unit. I tried multiplication because [link]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc() says 'at least one of the arguments must be a number' so it sounded hopeful, but still didn't work.

Comment: @AHaworth I don't think it's a FF bug per the [resolution here](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/4874#issuecomment-614138114) quirky parsing of properties (i.e. unitless parsing) does not apply to calc.

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks - interesting, I was misled by the MDN statement on multiplication which made it sound like 2 unitless would be OK.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use units if you want to use calc in CSS, per [this resolution](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/4874#issuecomment-614138114)

Fortunately calc with units works on Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.withCalc line,
.withoutCalc line {
  stroke-dasharray: 190px;
}
.withCalc line {
  stroke-dashoffset: calc(190px / 2);
}
.withoutCalc line {
  stroke-dashoffset: 95px;
}
```

```html
<svg class="withCalc" viewBox="0 0 200 200" width="200" height="200">
  <line x1="5" y1="100" x2="195" y2="100" stroke="black"/>
</svg>
<svg class="withoutCalc" viewBox="0 0 200 200" width="200" height="200">
  <line x1="5" y1="100" x2="195" y2="100" stroke="black"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: You're right! I tested this in my more complex actual code before asking, and it didn't make a difference. But it absolutely fixes things in this minimal example. In my real code, the CSS is within a `<style>` tag within the inline SVG. I wonder if that changes things. Safari's dev tools throw a warning when units are included in that case. I'll try to isolate and will post another question if I can replicate in a minimal example.