# my SVG (donnut chart) doesn't display correctly on IOS

Tags: html, css, svg

Context : I want to display a donut chart using one SVG composed of two circles :

[image: Final result]

- **Both circles are dynamically filled with a css variable** (as a percent).

Everythings works fine on PC and Android (chrome).

**When viewing with an iPhone**, the green circle is fully filled hiding the grey circle.

Below is the result as seen with IOS phone (tried Safari and Chrome) :

[image]

Here is a snippet, took 45% for green and 75% for grey

Code :

```css
:root {
  --val: 0;
}

svg {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.percent {
  stroke-dasharray: 100;
  stroke-dashoffset: calc(100 - var(--val));
}

.white {
  transform: rotate(135deg)
}

.forty-five{
  --val: 45;
}

.complete {
   --val: 75;
 }
```

```html
<div class="svg-container">
  <svg width="250" height="250" viewBox="0 0 140 140">
  <circle class="percent complete" cx="70" cy="70" r="52" fill="none" stroke="#e6e6e6" strokeWidth="18" pathLength="100" />
  <circle class="percent" cx="70" cy="70" r="52" fill="none" stroke="#333" strokeWidth="18" pathLength="100" />
  <circle class="percent forty-five" cx="70" cy="70" r="52" fill="none" stroke="#6AA617" strokeWidth="18" pathLength="100" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Any suggestion or any other way to obtain this result ?

**EDIT** : I just found out that there is the same problem when using Firefox on pC

Comment: When I open this stackoverflow page on my ios phone, the same problem happens

Comment: Experimenting using inspect on FF (Windows 10) it seems that stroke-dashoffset does not deal well with a calc as a value. If you put 25 in there instead then it seems to work. Using an intermediary step - setting --temp to calc(100 - 25) and using that also doesn't work.

Comment: I think this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72533352/my-svg-donnut-chart-doesnt-display-correctly-on-ios covers the problem.

Comment: @AHaworth your link redirect to this same thread (here)

Comment: Apologies, the link I'd intended to put is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65849051/calc-not-working-with-stroke-dashoffset-in-safari-and-firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **@A Haworth** already pointed out:
css `calc` support for svg properties is still rather spotty (might work in Chrome but not in Firefox – might also depend on the actual svg element and certain properties.
Probably fixed and negligible in the near future ... unless ie returns).

But you don't really need it anyway.

Since your horseshoe gauge should render only 270° of a 360° circle, you could instead tweak the `pathLength` property:

The ideal `pathLength` would be 133.333
360/270*100
(i.e. the 270° part of the circle will result in a computed circumference of 100 svg units)

Now you can use css-variable to display percentage based values:

```css
:root {
  --val: 100;
  --dashGap: 133.333;
  --offset: 0;
}

svg {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.percent {
  stroke-dashoffset: var(--offset);
  stroke-dasharray: var(--val) var(--dashGap)
}
```

```html
<div class="svg-container">
  <svg width="250" height="250" viewBox="0 0 140 140">
    <defs>
          <circle id="circle" cx="70" cy="70" r="52" fill="none" pathLength="133.333" stroke-width="18" />
    </defs>
   <!-- bg circle -->
    <use class="percent complete" href="#circle" stroke="#e6e6e6" />
   <!-- percentage circles -->
    <use class="percent" href="#circle" stroke="green" style="--val:50"/>
    <use class="percent" href="#circle" stroke="pink" style="--val:25; --offset:-50" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

If you need to render values progressively like 50% + 25% (so a total of 75%) you can use a `stroke-dahoffset` variable.
Each new segment needs to have a negative offset according the previous segments's percentage.